# Draggable cancel triggering blur event

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I have a draggable div which of course could be dragged around. 
Inside, I have input text which has two events (focus and blur). 
Also inside, I have another div which serve as draggable cancellation div (dragging that div prevent any drag to occur).

you could see it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/wUDzh/4/

- Clicking the input box would trigger focus event and clicking outside main div (the red one) would trigger blur event. This is fine.
- Clicking or dragging the main div would NOT trigger blur event. That's what I want.
- The problem is, clicking the cancellation div (the blue one) cause blur event of the input box to occur. Which is make sense, but that's not what I want.

is there any way to prevent blur event to occur just like the behavior of the main div?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the input field from blurring when you click the cancellation `div`, simply do:

```
    $('#cancel').mousedown(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wUDzh/7/)

Comment: lol I actually tried to do just like that, but using click event. But in my case, if I use click event, blur event would be triggered before the click event occur. Mousedown solve it! thx

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
$("#text").blur(function(e)
{
   // alert('a');
    if(e.target.id === 'text'){
        //this prevents other blur handlers from firing
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        //this prevent the default action and returns
        return false;
    }
   $(this).val("I've got blur");
});
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/wUDzh/6/